# Loading PDFs into iBooks programmatically

Tags: pdf, iphone

I have a client that wants to put their course materials, which are already in PDF format into the iBook PDF section on the iPhone/iPad devices. I have loaded one of the PDFs and it looks great but the process is very manual and the end users are not very tech savvy or patient.

Is there a way where I can provide a link on a website that will either load the PDF into their iBook catalog if they are navigating from the device(iPhone/iPad) or load it into iTunes if they are on their PC?

As an aside would you think that a single iBook PDF would be preferrable to 26 different iBook PDFs, the course materials are currently broken into lessons. The initial download times would pretty much be the same, if there is an automated process. The concern for me is the order the PDFs are displayed on the device and that the library would look cluttered and make the overall experience less than ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer this for completeness purposes. There is not currently (9/2010) an automated process for installing a book into iBooks, there are a couple of apps that you can install on your iPhone/iPad and you can always import into your iTunes.

If something changes in the future I will update this answer.