# How to let a user access PDF files created by an application so that they can print them

Tags: ios, pdf, printing

Okay, so I have an app that generates reports for a Chiropractic clinic and allows the user to print them directly from iPad assuming they have an Airprint printer. I also am in the process of writing code that will allow the user to generate a PDF of the report so that they can email it/upload it to the cloud or somehow send it to some other device that will allow them to print it WITHOUT using AirPrint.

I know about sandboxing, but I also know that you can store PDFs on an iPad and view them through iBooks.

I read here: [Loading PDFs into iBooks programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399645/loading-pdfs-into-ibooks-programmatically) that there wasn't a way to do so back in 2010. The guy said he would update his answer, but you know how these things are

I also have a backdoor solution here: [Xcode save a PDF as Image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810209/xcode-save-a-pdf-as-image) turning the whole darn thing into a .png

Are there any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIDocumentInteractionController` to present a set of options to the user. Let the user choose what they want to do with the PDF.